# Jupyter notebook execution based on user entered automation parameters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, papermill

I am trying to build a service that would allow users using notebook to set automation parameters in a cell like the starting time as to when the notebook should start executing. The service would then take this input time and execute the notebook at the desired time and store the executed notebook to S3. I have looked into `papermill` but I believe there is no way to add automation parameters like start execution time using that. Is there any ways to achieve this? Or is there a way papermill can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Papermill handles just parameterizing and executing the notebooks, not scheduling. For that, you need to use another tool. You can build something yourself on top of Apache Airflow which seems to be the most widespread scheduler for such case. It has a native support for Papermill (see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/papermill.html)). Or you can use a ready tool like [Paperboy](https://github.com/timkpaine/paperboy).

To read in-depth about scheduling notebooks, take a look at the [article](https://netflixtechblog.com/scheduling-notebooks-348e6c14cfd6) by Netflix.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/tree/master/notebooks/tools/gcp-notebook-executor) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/dlvm/tools/scripts/notebook_executor.sh) for a wrapper that will schedule notebook execution

The shell scripts above create a VM, runs the notebook, saves the output and destroy the instance.

In [Google Cloud AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new) we provide a scheduling service which is in Beta now.